# Raspberry Pi 4: Black screen after boot both local and via vnc

Tags: pi-4, ssh, vnc, reboot

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 that I have had running for at least half a year as a Plex server.
I used Raspberry Pi  Imager to create the os, and then I connected via vnc from either my mac or my pc, the Pi has a fixed IP.

I am not very experienced in using unix or Raspberry Pi´s, I have done the setup using guides and videos.

I have not had any issues, remember to go on the Pi and install updates regularly, but after the last reboot, I can no longer connect.

When I connect from VNC I get "Connot currently show the desktop".
If I add a monitor, I can see it boot up, show the initial splash screen, and then a black screen.

When I try to connect from a terminal I get "Permission denied, please try again." I am pretty sure I left the password standard (raspberry), but I am not 100 % sure, I could have been clever and found a good password, but I have only used vnc since the installation.

I can still connect to the shared folder and see the files on the USB drive connected to the pi.

I would rather not reinstall the os, since I spent a lot of time setting up my collection in plex, with covers and collections.

I tried adding init=/bin/sh at the end of cmdline.txt, and boot up, but that did not work.

When I run ssh -v pi@192.168.1.39 I get:

```
PS C:\Users\steff> ssh -v pi@192.168.1.39
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.39 [192.168.1.39] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Raspbian-5+deb11u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Raspbian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.39:22 as 'pi'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:l472kVY1iIjNJ1t9QGS3iNOfTJ6QRSi63r1ZWULedv4
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.1.39' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steff/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.1.39's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.39's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@192.168.1.39's password:
```

Hope someone has a brilliant idea of how to fix it. Please let me know
Or If I forgot to give any info

Comment: So no answers, and I could not get it fixed. I scraped the PI and bought a cheap Windows PC, that runs my Plex.